# Android SDK specific resources in the APK

Tags: java, android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUFLP.png)

As highlighted in the image i am observing that APK contains all the Android SDk specific resources in it and is making APK size bigger by 3 MB.

Any one help me how can i avoid this during the application build.

I was using compileSDKVersion 23. After migrating to 30 i am seeing this issue.

Any help would be much appriciated.

I was using compileSDKVersion 23. After migrating to 30 i am seeing this issue.

I would like t use the compileSDKVersion 30 and i am expecting that apk shouldn't contain the android sdk resources as i am not referring to those in my app.

Comment: The size of the resources on your screenshot seems negligible (less than 0.5%). What is actually (much) bigger ? Did you change something else , like minSdk, dependencies versions ?

Comment: I have attached only one screenshot. Actually all the resources(drawables, anims, xmls, layouts etc..) from sdk are getting added to apk. 
Yes i have upgraded minSDKVersion to 19. Earlier it was 10.

To be specific All the folders under (Android\Sdk\platforms\android-30\data\res) are getting included in the apk.

Comment: I thought the problem was the size increase. These files are part of the platform (the OS) and should not be included in an apk, even if they are referenced in the application (regardless of the sdk version). Do they appear in Android Studio's project view ?

Comment: I don't see them in the project view

Answer (score 0):

**ShrinkResources is useful to reduce the dimension of your generated APK, stripping out any unused resource.**

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        multiDexEnabled true
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I have set those already and proguard is enabled in my build. but still i see the issue.

Comment: this is not sdk files. try to delete